# How to transform one queue type to another queue

Tags: c++, queue

I have below simple model class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>

template<typename idType>
struct Compartment {
    std::optional<idType> value_;
    Compartment() {
        value_ = std::nullopt;
    }
    Compartment(idType value): value_ {value} {
    }
    
    std::optional<idType> getValue() const {
        return value_;
    }
};
```

I can use above class somewhere in my code as follows:

```
    std::queue<Compartment<float>> myQueue;
    myQueue.emplace(1.2);
    myQueue.emplace();
    myQueue.emplace();
    myQueue.emplace(1.8);
```

I also want to calculate average of myQueue. So i created a function:

```
template<typename T>
std::optional<T> calcAverage(std::queue<std::optional<T>>& myQueue) {
    return std::nullopt;
}
    
template<>
std::optional<float> calcAverage<float>(std::queue<std::optional<float>>& myQueue) {
    float sum = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    while( !myQueue.empty() ) {
        if (myQueue.front()) {
            sum += *myQueue.front();
            count++;
        }
        myQueue.pop();
        
    }
    if (count != 0) return sum / count;
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

But the function i created take `std::queue<std::optional<float>>`. But i am creating queue as
`std::queue<Compartment<float>>`. What is the most proper way to transform one type queue to another type queue?

Comment: The Compartment class of your adds no value whatsoever to optional that it enwraps so just erase it and life is easier for everybody.

Comment: A queue may not be the best data structure if you need to compute the average of all its elements. Even if you throw it away once you have the average, it is probably easier to do with a simple `std::vector` that you leave to get destroyed afterward.

Comment: yep, if you need to look through a queue, don't use `std::queue` which forces you to `pop` each element. `std::queue` is just a wrapper round some other container (`std::deque` by default), use that container instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your greatest issue is that you are using the container adapter `std::queue`, which intentionally doesn't support iteration. This forces you to `push` and `pop` to insert into another queue, which is cumbersome and inefficient.

Instead, use `std::deque`, which is not an adapter, but an actual container with iterators and many more features.
With `std::deque`, you have multiple options for how to implement such a copy:

```cpp
// C++17 implementation using the std::transform algorithm
std::deque<std::optional<float>> transform_cpp17(
    const std::deque<Compartment<float>> &source)
{
    std::deque<std::optional<float>> result;
    std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
        [](Compartment<float> c) {
            return c.getValue();
        });
    return result;
}

// C++20 implementation using ranges
std::deque<std::optional<float>> transform_cpp20(
    const std::deque<Compartment<float>> &source)
{
    auto view = source | std::views::transform(&Compartment<float>::getValue);
    return {view.begin(), view.end()};
}

// C++23 simplified version of C++20 implementation
std::deque<std::optional<float>> transform_cpp23(
    const std::deque<Compartment<float>> &source)
{
    return {
        std::from_range,
        source | std::views::transform(&Compartment<float>::getValue)
    };
}
```

Note that if you are using `std::deque`, and iteration is possible, then you don't need to `push()` and `pop()` to calculate the average either.

```cpp
std::optional<float> calcAverage(
    const std::deque<std::optional<float>> &myQueue)
{
    float sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (const auto& optX : myQueue) {
        if (optX) {
            sum += *optX;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    return sum / count;
}
```

#### Further Notes

It's worth rethinking whether you need `Compartment` at all, since it's not doing anything that `std::optional` can't do already, from the looks of it.

Comment: Shouldnt  you check if the optional has value Before ```sum += *optX;```? Also If the entire deque has an empty optional value, shouldn't we return nullopt?

Comment: @Metropol_Tilkisi yeah, I've corrected it in the answer

Comment: Compartment actually contains other variables. I've removed these for simplicity.